# How can I populate Bullet points through AMP script

Tags: ampscript, content-builder, content, marketing-cloud

I wanted to understand how I can populate bullet points through AMP script in an email when my imported file has a column of values separated like this below:

*hazelcast-hibernate5 (devOpsHazelcast);Kubernetes Discovery Plugin for Hazelcast (devOpsHazelcast);*

All the records have a different number of fields that being said they will have a different number of bullet points in the email.

It would be helpful if you could provide me the right AMP script.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Turn your data into a row set using [BuildRowSetFromString()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/buildrowsetfromstring.htm) and then loop around the records in your row set:

```
Here's my bullet list
<ul>
    %%[
      SET @bulletContent = "hazelcast-hibernate5 (devOpsHazelcast);Kubernetes Discovery Plugin for Hazelcast (devOpsHazelcast);"
      SET @bulletRS = BuildRowSetFromString(@bulletContent,";")
      FOR @i = 1 TO Subtract(RowCount(@bulletRS),1) DO
        ]%%
        <li>%%=Field(Row(@bulletRS,@i),1)=%%</li>
        %%[
      NEXT @i
    ]%%
</ul>
Thanks
```

Outputs this content:

[image]